# Handle different method request in slim framework 3

Tags: slim

Hey i am learning slim framework 3 it may be a newbie question,

in the documentation i see a way to kind of group the request using `map()` like this

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
// Create new book or list all books
});
```

How do i handle each request, say i wanna handle `GET` request where do i put the logic in my controller?

i have tried to work around it using this :

```
//category routes
$app->group('/category', function(){
    $this->get('', 'CategoryController:getCategories');
    $this->post('', 'CategoryController:insertCategory');
});
```

and it worked just fine, but still how do i handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

When the GET and POST handling is different, I would prefer your working approach.

With one route for multiple methods you need to manually check for POST/GET (when something different should be done).

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $method = $request->getMethod();
    switch($method) {
        case 'POST':
            // insert category
            break;
        case 'GET':
            // get categories
            break;
        default:
            return $response->write('Could not handle request');
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay just assume they both is equal, will there be any different in term of performance or any other than the code itself? (sorry for asking different question)

Comment: @AchmadNaufalSyafiq Internally the call with `->map` would be equal to using one with `->get` and `->post`, see [sourcecode](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/blob/master/src/RouteCollector.php#L36)